# Where can I find jumping technique demos for the current version of Urban Terror?

Tags: urban-terror

On [this page](http://www.www0.org/cgi-bin/urtj?html=urtjq3.html) I found diverse jumping techniques for UT, but the demo files are for a previous version and do not work in current version.

Can someone provide a resource for demo files for jumping for the new version?

Answer (score 3):

a very good place to look for jumping techniques is
[UrtJumpers](http://www.urtjumpers.com/)

However there 2 kinds of demos there. Most demos are just plain video streams, which can be found in the Downloads section of the site. Take [BST Jumps](http://www.urtjumpers.com/map.php?id=284) for example. Click on the two first pictures to see the video streams of the map. You can also click on "show 4 records on this map" to get to a page, where you can download plain .dm_68 demo files for urban terror. The maps are also voted for they difficulty. Check the maps with high difficulty, above 6, to see advanced techniques like backjumping.

The demos might not exactly explain the jumps, but they show, how they are done and there are a lot of them.

Comment: Very interesting resources. I hope to be able to jump like some people some day, as I am still a noob :(

Comment: those people are jumping like 4 or 5 hours a day, it is nearly impossible to get to this if you have to work ;)